# jquery scrolling opacity feature

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to hide a div called "#left_column" while scrolling down a page.

The #left_column should be visible again when you begin to scroll up (not only when you are at the top of the page.)

What I need is exactly what you see here: https://www.ssense.com/women

I found this code but it is only visible again when I am at the top of the page and another issue is when you scroll fast, it does not respond.

```
var target = $('#left_column'); var targetHeight = target.outerHeight(); $(document).scroll(function(e){
var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
if(scrollPercent >= 0){
    target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
} });
```

I would very much appreciate your help on this!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: got a fiddle to play around with? :D

Comment: The post from MrUpsidown is really close to the result, only thing is that it is not working with chrome because chrome scrolls down automatically when you scroll to top. http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/eq948/

Comment: am on chrome and it works fine

Comment: Check it out here: http://aacopenhagen.com/en/161-view-all

Comment: Works fine here as well, left column under `View All` is hidden if i scroll down, shows if I scroll up, displayed if I scroll to top (on chrome)

Comment: Try to scroll further up even when you are at the top of the page. Then when you release it gets hidden.

Comment: I have tryed to illustrate here: http://www.nordicapparel.com/hidden.jpg

Using Mac and Chrome 36.0.1985.125

Comment: When you are at the top of the page and force the page to scroll further up and then releases, the browser acts like the page is being scrolled down.

Comment: Maybe its your mouse, I tried with up/down keys to force it to go as top as possible and still nothing, I used my mouse to scroll to top (and even when I was on top I was keep srolling) and still nothing, it worked as expected

Comment: I tryed both with my mouse and my mousepad, same thing happens. Please see here a video I just made: http://www.nordicapparel.com/hidden.mov

Comment: No it is a behavior of Mac OS X.

Comment: This site does not have the same behavior issue with my Mac OS X: https://www.ssense.com/women
Can you see a way around this behavior issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can Use ScrollTop() function in jquery to handle this job

```
$('#toTop').fadeIn();
var LastPos = 0;
var CurrentPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    CurrentPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (CurrentPos > LastPos) {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('#toTop').show();
    }       
    LastPos = CurrentPos;
});
```

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjXSq/959/)

Comment: He said `"not only when you are at the top of the page"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! It works great for fading out, but I need it to fade in as soon as I scroll up, even if I am not at the top of the page

Comment: @Alexandros oh sorry, I have corrected the code above

Comment: It works fine in firefox, but not with chrome on my mac. 
When you are at the top of the page and force the page to scroll further up and then releases, the browser acts like the page is being scrolled down and it fades out. (Illustration: http://www.nordicapparel.com/hidden.jpg)

Comment: Works as requested now, bad news are am not the one that down-votted you :P

Comment: This is exaclty the same code than in my answer. You can expect the same behavior...

Comment: Your code works fine, but with Mac OS X, the described behavior is happening with both Safari and Chrome! (illustrated here: www.nordicapparel.com/hidden.mov) I found a site that does not have the same behavior issue with my Mac OS X: ssense.com/women Do you know what they might have done to come around this issue?

Comment: No need to post the same comment on every post.

Comment: Solved adding `if (CurrentPos > 200)`

Comment: ` $('#left_column').fadeIn();
var LastPos = 0;
var CurrentPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    CurrentPos = $(this).scrollTop();
     
    if (CurrentPos > LastPos)  {
  if (CurrentPos > 200) {
        $('#left_column').fadeOut();}
    } else {
        $('#left_column').fadeIn();
    }
    
        
    LastPos = CurrentPos;
});`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `scrollTop` method and check if scrolling up or down:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {

        $('#box').hide();
    } else {

        $('#box').show();
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/eq948/)</kbd>

**Edit:**

To help you to **debug**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    // Add this line to log the 2 values in your console
    console.log(scrollTop, lastScrollTop);

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {

        $('#box').hide();
    } else {

        $('#box').show();
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Hi, it works great for scrolling up and down. But when I am at the very top of the page it gets hidden again for some reason? http://aacopenhagen.com/en/161-view-all

Comment: I believe this has something to do with chrome, if your scroll up the page bounces back (and scrolls down)

Comment: Using Chrome `Version 36.0.1985.125 m` and I can't reproduce the issue you described.

Comment: Still can't reproduce. *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function* might be unrelated but you should try to fix this error. Try to log `scrollTop` and `lastScrollTop` to see what happens.

Comment: When you are at the top of the page and force the page to scroll further up and then releases, the browser acts like the page is being scrolled down.

Comment: It happens both in Chrome and in Safari. But not in Firefox because here you cannot force the page further up when you are already at the top of the page.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested above?

Comment: The TypeError is unrelated, here you do not find the error: http://aacopenhagen.com/en/all/929-ashley-low-cut-zipper-boot.html

Comment: I dont know how to log scrollTop and lastScrollTop like you suggested?

Comment: How can you do web development without using the console? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

Comment: Your right, it is a Mac OS X behavior issue!
I found a site that does not have the same behavior issue with my Mac OS X: 

https://www.ssense.com/women

Do you know what they might have done to come around this issue?

Comment: One word: debug! Use your console, log the 2 variables as I told you 45 minutes ago and you should be able to understand what happens and eventually how to correct it. I do not have a mac here. I cannot debug for you. You were given a solution or at least a few hints. Your turn now.

Comment: Hi, it is not that I have not been trying, I am just having trouble figuring it out. I will continue trying...